# Augment and Prune a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, select, copy

I need a little advice concerning a MySQL operation:

There is a database A wich yields several tables. With a query I selected a set of entries out of this database to *copy* these results into another table of database B.
Now the table in database B contains the results of my query on database A.

For instance the query is:

```
SELECT names.name,ages.age FROM A.names names A.ages ages WHERE ages.name = name.name;
```

And to copy these results into database B I would run:

```
INSERT INTO B.persons (SELECT name,age FROM A.names names A.age age WHERE age.name = name.name);
```

Here's my question: When the data of database A has changed I want to run an "update" on the table of database B.
So, the easy and dirty approach would be: Truncate the table in database B, re-run the query on database A and copy the result back to database B.

But isn't there a smarter way so that only new result rows of that query will be copied and those entries in database B which are not in database A anymore get deleted?

In short: Is there a way to "augment" the table of database B with new entries and "prune" old entries out?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do two things:
1) Ensure you have a primary key that's either an integer or a unique combination of columns at a minimum in database B
2) Use logical deletes instead of physical deletes i.e. have a boolean deleted column

Point 2 ensures you never have to delete and lose data, you just update the flag and in your queries put `where deleted = 0` or `where deleted is null`.

When combined with a primary key it means everything can be handled easily by an `INSERT ... WITH DUPLICATE KEY` which will insert new rows and update existing ones - which means it can perform your 'deletes' at the same time too.

Comment: I'm a big advocate of never physically deleting data since you never know when you're going to need to restore or retrieve records for some other purpose like audits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
That's absolutely what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like you want to replicate the table. There is no simple quick fix for what you describe. You could of course write some application logic to do it but it would not be so efficient as it would have to compare each entry in each table and then delete or update accordingly.

One solution would be to setup a [foreign-key index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) between A and B and cascade updates and deletes to B. But this would only partly solve the problem. It would drop rows in B if they were deleted in A and it would update a key column in B if it were updated in A. But it would not update the other columns. Note also that this would require your table type to be INNODB.

Another would be to run inserts on B with A's values but use

[INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)....

Again this would work fine for updates but not for Deletes.

You could try to setup actual MySQL replication but this is perhaps beyond the scope of your problem and is more involved.

Finally you could set up the foreign key index as described above and write a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) that whenever an updates is applied to A then the corresponding key row in B is also updated. This seems like a plausible solution for you while not the cleanest I would admit.

It would seem that a small batch script run periodically on which ever environment your running on to duplicate the table would be the best to achieve what you are looking for.